# Getting unified system logs from an iOS device

Tags: ios, logging, oslog

I'm trying to use unified logging to log messages and retrieve them from a device for inspection. I created a new `OSLog` instance with

```
let logDebug = OSLog(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, category: "⚠️ debug")
```

Then I log messages with

```
os_log("%@", log: logDebug, type: OSLogType.debug, String(format:message, arguments: formatArgs))
```

This works fine in the Xcode console. It's supposed to be possible to retrieve these logs from an Xcode device by

- Doing a sysdiagnose (as [Apple explains here](https://download.developer.apple.com/iOS/iOS_Logs/sysdiagnose_Logging_Instructions.pdf))
- Transferring the sysdiagnose to a Mac, and then
- Inspecting the log (in `system_logs.logarchive`) with Console.app or the `log` command line tool.

When I do this, none of my logs are shown. No logs with the expected subsystem (bundle ID) are shown.

*However*, if I examine the log files in `system_logs.logarchive` directly via `grep` or `vim`, the messages are present. So they're in the logs, but for some reason neither Console.app nor `log` will show them. I made sure that Console.app is set to show "all messages" and I haven't entered any search terms.

What step am I missing, or what detail needs to be different?

Comment: Could you please indicate the versions of Xcode and iOS where these issues are present?

Comment: It's whatever was current in 2018 when I wrote the question. Probably iOS 12 and Xcode 10 but I can't be certain at this point.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have no luck with `OSLogType.debug`. Console cannot show this kind of log.

But others work perfectly.
Please try then check them in Console app.
`os_log("%@", log: logDebug, type: OSLogType.info, String(format:"%i", arguments: [1]))`

`os_log("%@", log: logDebug, type: OSLogType.error, String(format:"%i", arguments: [1]))`

even:

`os_log("%@", log: logDebug, type: OSLogType.default, String(format:"%i", arguments: [6]))`